# Elastic Range Search Failure

Tags: php, elasticsearch

My range filter keeps failing on my windows elastic 1.4 instance. It gives no error just returns no records.

```
  PUT reseller_api_logging
  {
    "mappings": {
      "record": { 
      "properties": { 
        "PastelAccountNumber":    { "type": "string"  }, 
        "CreatedAt":     { "type": "date" ,"format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }, 
        "HTTPmethod":     { "type": "string"  }, 
        "ContentTypeRequest":     { "type": "string"  }, 
        "Endpoint":     { "type": "string"  }, 
        "RequestParams":     { "type": "string" , "index": "not_analyzed" }, 
        "RawResponse":     { "type": "string" , "index": "not_analyzed" }, 
        "Response":     { "type": "string" , "index": "not_analyzed" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the range query:

```
GET reseller_api_logging/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "CreatedAt" : {
                  "gte" : "2017-01-01 01:01:49",
                "lte" : "2017-01-30 09:01:49"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a piece of one of the documents return on a match all search:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 50,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "reseller_api_logging",
            "_type": "logging",
            "_id": "2142183",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "PastelAccountNumber": "103206",
               "CreatedAt": "2017-01-23 09:01:49",
               "HTTPmethod": "GET",
               "Endpoint": "getServiceSessionDetailsById",
               "RequestParams": "
```

Comment: does in return hits as [] ?

Comment: did you try using the keywords "now" and periods from here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-range-query.html ? (Just to verify dates are working!)

Comment: Yes it returns the hits as []

Comment: I tried to use the now and the now-1d/d nothing would work with the mapping yet my other indexes havent had an issue

Comment: If someone can send one that works for them and I will try it my side